# Does mandatory in MySQL Workbench mean, that referencing field cannot be NULL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm designing database and I'm curious about does mandatory checkbox in mysql workbench mean, that field should be null or to what does mandatory in this situation refer?

Later if necessary I will include an image of this table where this question occurred.

Tanks every on for help.

**UPD:**
I must say, that after I generated models SQL and looked at both tables I didn't see anything different. I'm starting to think, that this mandatory option is displayed only visually, but in functional way it doesn't mean anything.

If I'm wrong someone please help. Tanks again.

Comment: ...create a database from the model and see for yourself?

Comment: That's actually a good idea. Will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came to a conclusion that this is just a visual effect to show, that the relationship is mandatory. This option doesn't affect the generated SQL code in anyway.

Comment: exactly! After hours of confusion I reached the same argument. Does mysql itself, support this concept at all?

Comment: You are not right, if you set the Referenced Table as mandatory, the referencing ID is set to NN (not null).

Answer (score 9):

Ok, I found it.

Let's say you have one table called `User` and a second called `Address` and you want to make a relation between them. The example might look like this:

> *User*
>  id 
>  Name
>
> *Address*
>  id 
>  user_id 
>  street

So you have a foreign key in `Address` for the `User`. If you make this relation, all fields are mandatory, so `user_id` is a primary key field it is not null, and `Address`-`id` is even the same, but what is `Address`-`user_id`? Is it really a part of primary key in `Address`? No, it doesn't help you to identify a row in this table. So the `Address`-`user_id` could be null, maybe you only got an `Address` or the table `Address` is even referenced by a table company.

The thing is, the mandatory checkbox on the "Referencing Table"-side is only for visual effects, on the opposite the checkbox on the "Referenced Table"-side makes the field nullable or not.

If mandatory, the field Address-user_id never could be null. If not mandatory, the field can be null for one row of data and no constrained will be affected.

Comment: "visual effects" that's a veeery nice way to say MySQL Workbench really sucks here. After hours of googling, I found this tread. Should I also say that all "mandatory" one-to-one-or-many relationships Wbnch shows (for... hmm... "visual effects") are in fact one-to-ZERO-or-many? There is no mechanism in RDBMSs to enforce a parent to have at least one child. Thanks for this thread, guys...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it means the field value cannot be `NULL`. I say most likely because I cannot find the "mandatory" word anywhere in MySQL Workbench here.

Comment: When you create a realtionship and double click it, you can find it in second tab. Maybe now it would be clearer.